# ACPI log reboot

Tags: linux

I try google but not some info useful. I try debug why my server reboot. I have some log from ACPI. With this log have someone press power button on my server?

```
[root ~]# grep -i acpi /var/log/messages-20150726

Jul 25 04:10:33 node-dev kernel: [ 0.607577] pnp: PnP ACPI init
Jul 25 04:10:33 node kernel: [ 0.607589] ACPI: bus type pnp registered
Jul 25 04:10:33 node-dev kernel: [ 0.609994] pnp: PnP ACPI: found 14
devices
Jul 25 04:10:33 node-dev kernel: [ 0.609996] ACPI: ACPI bus type pnp
unregistered
Jul 25 04:10:33 node-dev kernel: [ 0.970521] acpiphp: ACPI Hot Plug
PCI Controller Driver version: 0.5
Jul 25 04:10:33 node-dev kernel: [ 0.971123] ACPI: Power Button [PWRB]
Jul 25 04:10:33 node-dev kernel: [ 0.971171] ACPI: Power Button [PWRF]
Jul 25 04:10:33 node-dev kernel: [ 0.972378] ACPI: SSDT
00000000bf79ffa0 007DD (v01 PmRef P001Cst 00003001 INTL 20051117)
Jul 25 04:10:33 node-dev kernel: [ 7.786393] ACPI Warning: SystemIO
range 0x0000000000000828-0x000000000000082f conflicts with OpRegion
0x0000000000000800-0x000000000000084f (\PMRG) (20090903/utaddress-254)
Jul 25 04:10:33 node-dev kernel: [ 7.786402] ACPI: If an ACPI driver
is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
```

Update:

I get some info log about that time:

```
I get some info log about that time:



    [root ~]# who -b 
    system boot 2015-07-25 04:10 

    [root ~]# last -x reboot 
    reboot system boot 2.6.32-042stab10 Sat Jul 25 04:10 - 20:10


   [root@node-dev ~]# grep tty /var/log/messages*
    /var/log/messages-20150726:Jul 25 04:10:33 node-dev kernel: [    0.000000] console [tty0] enabled
    /var/log/messages-20150726:Jul 25 04:10:33 node-dev kernel: [    1.236001] serial8250: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4) is a 16550A
    /var/log/messages-20150726:Jul 25 04:10:33 node-dev kernel: [    1.480012] serial8250: ttyS1 at I/O 0x2f8 (irq = 3) is a 16550A
    /var/log/messages-20150726:Jul 25 04:10:33 node-dev kernel: [    1.480270] 00:07: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4) is a 16550A
    /var/log/messages-20150726:Jul 25 04:10:33 node-dev kernel: [    1.480393] 00:08: ttyS1 at I/O 0x2f8 (irq = 3) is a 16550A
    /var/log/messages-20150726:Jul 25 07:52:18 node-dev init: tty (/dev/tty1) main process ended, respawning
```

Comment: What makes you assume that ACPI is the culprit?  `ACPI: Power Button` lines are detection of the presence of these devices - not that they have been operated.  Random reboots can be caused by software misconfiguration but more likely to be hardware related issue: bad PSU, loose power cable, inadequate cooling of CPU/RAM/GPU/IO etc.

Comment: I don't think ACPI is culprit. But Power Button PWRB and PWRF log give me some info about power button press intentionally?

Answer (score 1):

Based on this output it would appear that someone did indeed press the power button, though this could also be done virtually depending on the capabilities of the system using IPMI or some sort of OOB management interface like a KVM if configured appropriately.  If the system has a BMC and/or IPMI interface of some sort you should be able to access the Server/System Event Log(SEL) using `impitool <relevant connection options> sel list`.  [Accessing the SEL](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ipmitool) may give you more information about what happened around the time of the reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I get some info log about that time:

```
[root ~]# who -b
         system boot  2015-07-25 04:10
[root ~]# last -x reboot
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-042stab10 Sat Jul 25 04:10 - 20:10 


[root ~]# grep tty /var/log/messages*
/var/log/messages-20150726:Jul 25 04:10:33 node-dev kernel: [    0.000000] console [tty0] enabled
/var/log/messages-20150726:Jul 25 04:10:33 node-dev kernel: [    1.236001] serial8250: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4) is a 16550A
/var/log/messages-20150726:Jul 25 04:10:33 node-dev kernel: [    1.480012] serial8250: ttyS1 at I/O 0x2f8 (irq = 3) is a 16550A
/var/log/messages-20150726:Jul 25 04:10:33 node-dev kernel: [    1.480270] 00:07: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4) is a 16550A
/var/log/messages-20150726:Jul 25 04:10:33 node-dev kernel: [    1.480393] 00:08: ttyS1 at I/O 0x2f8 (irq = 3) is a 16550A
/var/log/messages-20150726:Jul 25 07:52:18 node-dev init: tty (/dev/tty1) main process ended, respawning
```